# Route authentication in TSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-typescript

I'm having a problem typing the route component in typescript

"The 'Component' binding element implicitly has a type 'any'.ts(7031)
var Component: any"

```
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isAuth } from '../services/Auth';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    isAuth() ?
      <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to="/user/login" />
  )} />
}
```

Comment: `export const PrivateRoute: React.FC<{component: React.Component} = ({component: Component, ...rest}) =>` or `export const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}: React.Props<{component: React.Component}>) =>`

Comment: the error still persists

Comment: It has to be a different error

Comment: Thanks, I solved it.
Typed the component: function